# web page design issue

Tags: c#, html, performance, visual-studio-2008, iis-7

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 to develop ASP.Net application on IIS 7.0 + Windows Server 2008. Using SQL Server 2008 as backend. My question is, in order to achieve best web page performance form end user perspective, any principles to follow? Any good tutorials or samples to learn?

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to usability principles? Most's usability considerations depend on your site's target audience and what they will be trying to achieve using your site.

Nielsen (2003), Brinck et al., (2002), and Costabile, (2001) define five components for defining usability. Firstly learnability should be considered in the design of a system. Learnability defines how quickly a new user can adapt to performing tasks on a system (Cappel & Huang, 2007).

Secondly efficiency should be considered, how much time, or how many steps does it take to complete a given task (Cappel & Huang, 2007). Generally the shorter amount of either measurement relates to a more efficient process, improving the users productivity.

Thirdly Nielsen (2003) and Brinck et al., (2002) believe that memorability should be measured. This is the ability for a user to remember how to complete tasks after a substained absence from using the system, allowing them to achieve full efficiency in a short space of time. Complex user interface designs which require users to create memory aids are not memorable.

Fourthly errors are a measure of usability. Preventing users from being exposed to situations they do not want to be in, can prevent them from leaving the system. Providing functionality to help the user recover from non-preventable errors can assist the user in dealing with the scenario instead of them feeling helpless.

Finally Nielsen (2003), Cappel & Huang, (2007), and Brinck et al., (2002) feel that satisfaction is a component of usability. How the user feels using the design whilst completing tasks is an indicator of its usability.

These are some principles I came across at Uni.